# FaceTime HD (internal) webcam not available - TB MBP 13" (late 2016)

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime, webcam

My FaceTime HD camera is refusing to work/show up as available for any of my camera-using apps (Facetime, Zoom, Photo Booth). The message I get in Facetime is "No Camera Available".

What I've tried so far:

- Resetting PRAM
- Resetting NVRAM
- Running diagnostics - no hardware issues found
- sudokilling VDCAssistant
- Restarting my MBP (obv)

None of these have done anything, but I have a hunch it's not a hardware issue for some reason. I occasionally run with an external monitor which is hooked up to its own dedicated webcam, I don't know if there can be some kind of adverse interaction between the two which may cause this to happen.

Any advice for troubleshooting this would be extremely welcome!

My full setup:

- Late 2016 4 port 13" TB MBP (2.9 i5)
- LG UltraFine 4K 24MD4KL-B (a number of external peripherals connected via USB-C: keyboard, mouse, headphone amplifier).

Comment: Make sure you also try an SMC reset: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Comment: Which macOS are you running?

Comment: @lhf I knew my post was missing something :s I'm running macOS Big Sur (20G165)

Comment: @KevinGrabher thanks for the advice. I just (re-)attempted that, no dice unfortunately. My current plan is to try updating my mac to macOS Monterey once it comes out today, and hope for the best.

Comment: Does the camera work if you login as another user without the external monitor plugged in?

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried creating a new user without any external peripherals connected, no luck there either

Comment: I just updated to macOS Monterey (12.01) to see whether that would help, but the camera is still undetectable. I'm starting to think the webcam is simply dead?